# Datatype time in mysql database, fetching using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakephp. I have one column in database as running_time. When I am getting the data using cakephp It is displaying something else like date. How to fix this?

> Data in database
>   00:01:48

**What I am getting**

```
[running_time] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
                        (
                            [time] => 2019-12-12T00:01:48+09:00
                            [timezone] => Asia/Tokyo
                            [fixedNowTime] => 
                        )
```

Comment: running_time is TIME column type?

Comment: Yes. running_time is a type of TIME

Comment: try $post->running_time->format('H:i:s');

Comment: Yes it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running_time is FrozenTime Object, then simple use format method like:

```
echo $post->running_time->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cake\I18n\Time` class to format date and time that is fetched from the database:
Suppose you are getting data in `output` variable:

```
$date = Time::parse($output['running_time']);
$time = $date->i18nFormat('HH:mm:ss');
echo $time;
```

[Cakephp -> Date & Time -> Formatting](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/time.html#formatting)